# .NET 4.5 support zip64

Tags: c#, .net, zip

Does .NET 4.5 support zipping and unzipping with zip64? I know some third party libraries such as dotnetzip support it but I was wondering if .NET classes such as ZipArchive or ZipFile supports it? And if not, then how come I am able to extract zip files with zip64 using windows explorer or using windows' default zip utility?

Answer (score 2):

I can confirm that ZipArchive will create zip64 archives automatically if required, I haven't tested uncompression but I'd be surprised if it wasn't supported!

Answer (score -2):

Dot NET framework 4.5 provides some new classes in **System.IO.Compression** namespace that allows us to do.

Using these classes we can do following :

> 1.create new Zip files.
>
> 2.open and modify existing Zip files
>
> 3.extract the contents of Zip files

Comment: I am using .net 4.5 and I'm using the ZipArchive class however I am not able to extract a certain zip file and I think it may be because it was zipped using dotnetzip and was saved with zip64 extension. my question is does .net support unzipping files with zip64 extension and if not, how come it is supported when I extract the same file in windows (right click-extrac all)